# Using a one-line unless or if statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, unless

I am new to Ruby.  I am looking for an elegant one line solution to this line of code:

```rb
puts "Year: ".colorize(:light_blue) + "#{instrument.year}"
```

I would like it to print `"N/A"` if `instrument.year` is `""` (an empty string).  I imagine an unless, if or || might work, but so for nothing has quite worked for me.  Still learning!  I have several fields that need this treatment, so I'd like to avoid an if/else/end statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why "elegant one line"? That's an artificial constraint; A single line can result in a very convoluted solution that is harder to maintain.

Comment: Please post a complete working example. It's hard to refactor code when the code is lacking context or isn't executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but what I understood is you want to display `instrument.year` or `N/A` if `instrument.year` is an empty string.

So what I would do is use a [ternary](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/):

```
puts "Year: ".colorize(:light_blue) + "#{instrument.year.empty? ? 'N/A' : instrument.year}"
```

Comment: Yes!  I finally did something like you suggested. It turned out that some fields were either empty strings or NILs, so I needed an || in there to account for that. But it works and is the least cluttered solution for the code!  Thx!